# Using tern migrations in go test containers with postgres

Tags: postgresql, go, testcontainers

I am trying to write integration tests for my Postgres database. For that I am using testcontainers in Go. I already am using tern migrations in my actual database and have the migrations in the migrations folder. The problem is that some of my migrations use the properties from the .tern.conf file as these values can differ depending on the environment. I created a similar config file for local as local.tern.conf and tried setting global variable. But for some reason when I run the migrations, these values are not getting picked. Here is an example-

```
func SetupTestDatabase() *TestDatabase {
    // Set the TERN_CONFIG environment variable to the path of your local.tern.conf file
    if err := os.Setenv("TERN_CONFIG", "../local.tern.conf"); err != nil {
        // Handle error if setting the environment variable fails
        zap.S().Fatal("failed to set TERN_CONFIG", err)
    }

    // setup db container
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*60)
    defer cancel()

    container, dbInstance, dbAddr, err := createContainer(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        zap.S().Fatal("failed to setup test", err)
    }

    conn, _ := dbInstance.Acquire(ctx)
    m, err := migrate.NewMigrator(ctx, conn.Conn(), "schema_version_table")
    if err != nil {
        zap.S().Fatal("failed to setup migrator", err)
    }

    if err := m.LoadMigrations("../migrations"); err != nil {
        zap.S().Fatal("failed to load migrations", err)
        return nil
    }

    if len(m.Migrations) == 0 {
        zap.S().Fatal("no migrations found")
        return nil
    }

    if err := m.Migrate(ctx); err != nil {
        zap.S().Fatal("failed to migrate", err)
        return nil
    }

    return &TestDatabase{
        container:  container,
        DbInstance: dbInstance,
        DbAddress:  dbAddr,
    }
}
```

here is what a part of my migration looks like-

```
....
CREATE TABLE {{.version_table}} (
    version integer NOT NULL
);

alter table {{.version_table}}
    owner to {{.master_user}};
.....
```

and here is the local.tern.conf-

```
[database]
 host = <host>
 port = 5432
 database = <db name>
 version_table = schema_version_table

[data]
 master_user = <user>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the config file must be targeting the random port provided by testcontainers-go instead of the default 5432 port for Postgres. You probably need to generate that file on the fly getting the host and the random port from testcontainers-go using the `Host` and `MappedPort` methods of the container. Please see https://golang.testcontainers.org/features/networking/#getting-the-container-host

```golang
ip, _ := nginxC.Host(ctx)
port, _ := nginxC.MappedPort(ctx, "80")
_, _ = http.Get(fmt.Sprintf("http://%s:%s", ip, port.Port()))
```

Could you try that?

Another option could be using "Testcontainers Desktop", which allows defining the ports for a given service (postgres), proxying any request to that port to the random one in a transparent manner. Please see https://knowledge.testcontainers.cloud/fixed-ports

> You can now configure the Testcontainers desktop app to also proxy these random ports to a fixed port on your machine, available to debug Testcontainers services. To do so, simply click "open config location" in the "Services" sub-menu. You can then clone the sample configuration file and rename it to my-service.toml, where "my-service" is whatever your service is actually called, and finally pick a fixed port that should always be available to debug the service. Once you save the file, it's detected and reloaded automatically.